# could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, postgresql

A user is complaining that his PostgreSQL client program is often disconnecting from the server when idle. I'm trying to troubleshoot the issue. I can see such occurrences in the server log:

```
2022-06-15 15:18:20 EEST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

    
2022-06-15 15:18:20 EEST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

The message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" seems to be the Windows equivalent of Linux's "Connection refused"; it is the message a client gets when it attempts to connect to a TCP port on a server, and the server refuses, typically because no process is listening on that port.

But here it is the **server** that gets that message. Apparently the client has connected to port 5432 of the server alright. The client and the server work together until at some point the server "could not receive data from client". How can it be possible that the reason for that is that the "target machine actively refused" a connection? The server doesn't attempt to connect to a port on the client, does it? (Even if it did, it is unlikely that the client would actively refuse a connection; more likely it would time out, as its firewall would filter the request.)

So what is the "target machine" here, and what kind of connection is it refusing?

This is an ancient PostgreSQL (8.3) on Windows Server 2019 64 bit.

Comment: Does this occur after a certain time elapse? Say, like connection only last for 1 minute?

Comment: I haven't yet talked directly with the affected user, but it seems that, yes, the connection lasts for a few minutes. It seems it drops when it's idle for a few (e.g. 5) minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the routers in between peers would actively close silent TCP connections. You need to enable the keepalive (auto PING PONG) feature by changing your postgresql.conf by changing these three lines in `postgresql.conf`:

```
tcp_keepalives_idle = 20 # automatically send PING after 20 second silence
tcp_keepalives_interval = 10 # a PING is failed after 10 seconds without a PONG
tcp_keepalives_count = 3 # 3 failed PING's would trigger closing connection
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I'm more familiar with Linux, and I'm confident that in this case it would give a different message than "Connection refused", such as "Connection reset". Does Windows give the same message in both cases?

Comment: You need to restart the postgreSQL after changing the above configuration for it to take effect. It will not break the TCP connection then just because silence breached some certain threshold.